# Подскажите по загрузке данных в Unity (архитектурное решение)

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, разработка-игр, сериализация

Рад Вас приветствовать

Введение: создаётся карточная игра с разными типами карт (например карты "Враг" и карты "Предмет"). Каждый тип имеет свои данные. Так как этих карт будет большое количество, было принято решение загружать данные о картах из json файла.

Пример загрузки карт типа "Враг":

```
{
 "AllEnemies": [
{
  "Id": 0,
  "CardName": "Big fly",
  "Stats": [ 0.5, 0, 5, 0.25, 70 ],
  "Sprites": [ "someSprite", "someSprite"]
},
{
  "Id": 1,
  "CardName": "Bug",
  "Stats": [ 0.5, 0.25, 30, 1.4, 15 ],
  "Sprites": [ "someSprite", "someSprite"]
}
}
```

Соответственно у других типов карт сериализуемые поля будут отличаться.

Вопрос: как архитектурно и в какой момент времени лучше сделать загрузку этих данных?

Рассказываю свою реализацию, которую я считаю громоздкой и неверной, но ничего лучше придумать пока что не могу

У меня есть абстрактный класс

```
public abstract class LoadCardsFromJson : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Texture2D _spriteSheet;
    protected Sprite[] allSprites;

    private void Awake()
    {
        allSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("CardSprites/" + _spriteSheet.name);
    }
    public abstract List<Card> LoadCardsFromFile(string fileName);
}
```

Который будет наследоваться классами, отвечающих за загрузку каждого типа карты, например загрузка карт врагов:

```
public class LoadEnemies : LoadCardsFromJson
{
    public override List<Card> LoadCardsFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        List<Card> returnEnemies = new List<Card>();
        //логика загрузки карт врагов
        return returnEnemies;
    }
}
```

Также есть абстрактный класс CardController,который будет наследоваться остальными контроллерами.

```
public abstract class CardController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CardView _cardView;
    private List<Card> _cards;

    public abstract void LoadCards();
}
```

Каждый класс, который унаследует CardController, должен будет реализовать метод LoadCards() и будет содержать в себе нужный Load класс

(для EnemyController - LoadEnemies, для ItemController - LoadItem, и т.д.)

Например, EnemyController будет выглядеть так:

```
public class EnemyController : CardController
{
    [SerializeField]
    private LoadEnemies _loadEnemies;

    private List<Card> _allEnemies = new List<Card>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        LoadCards();   
    }

    public override void LoadCards()
    {
        _allEnemies = _loadEnemies.LoadCardsFromFile("Enemies");
    }
```

На Unity сцене будет пустой GameObject, содержащий в себе все Controller'ы (EnemyController, ItemController и т.д.) и при запуске сцены в каждом будет запускаться метод Awake() и, соответственно, подгружаться все данные из json файлов

Но эта реализация мне очень не нравится по следующим причинам:

1. Дублирование кода для каждого типа
2. Для каждого нового типа данных мне нужно будет создавать большое количество кода, который уже написан, но используется чуть иначе в других типах карт

В связи с этим я ищу больше архитектурное решение моей проблемы, если это вообще проблема. Если можно этот код сделать более абстрактам и удободополняемым, я буду рад прочесть любые комментарии на этот счёт

P.S. Я думал о том, что это всё можно привязать через события, но так и не придумал как именно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LoadCardsFromJson`, судя по названию он из некого источника, и из json выдавать модели данных в виде соответствующих типу структур, но вместо этого вижу текстуры и спрайты... что? Подбором ресурсов по данным это другая ответственность. В `Unity3D` для этих дел есть [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html).

`LoadEnemies`, зачем он нужен не понимаю, при сериализации твоего одного большого джейсена выйдет что-то типа:

```
[Serializable]
public struct AllCardData
{
    public ItemCardData[] AllItems;
    public EnemyCardData[] AllEnemies;
}
```

Названия ужасные, почему нельзя просто `items` и `enemys`?

`CardController`... если не знаешь чем занимается класс и в чем его ответственность, назови его `controller`, древняя традиция. Есть визуализация, лист кард и еще грузит карты... что это? зачем это?

> Дублирование кода для каждого типа

Напиши метода в базовом классе и не придется дублировать его в наследниках, а просто вызывать метод.

> Для каждого нового типа данных мне нужно будет создавать большое количество кода, который уже написан, но используется чуть иначе в других типах карт

Что бы этого избежать, есть наследование, абстракция и вообще можно выделять поведения в самостоятельные классы.

---

Вообще это не имеет никакого смысла хранить и грузить все данные из json. Все карты в игре, их картинки, звуки, эффекты и т.д. изначально в проекте, а не на сервере, если добавляются новые, выпускается апдейт. Храня данные в тексте потом геморой связывать их с упомянутыми ресурсами, и вообще грузить... зачем это нужно?

Все можно хранить и настроить в `ScriptableObject`

```
public class CardData : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private string _name;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite _image;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip _useClip;
    ...
    
    public string Name => _name;
    public Sprite Image => _image;
    public AudioClip UseClip => _useClip;
    ...
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "UnitCard", menuName = "Card/Data/Unit")]
public class UnitCardData : CardData
{
    ...
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ItemCard", menuName = "Card/Data/Item")]
public class ItemCardData : CardData
{
    ...
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "CardsDataCollection", menuName = "Card/DataCollection")]
public class CardsDataHolder : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private CardData[] _collection;

    public IEnumerable<CardData> Collection => _collection;
    public IEnumerable<UnitCardData> UnitCollection =>
        _collection.Where(c => c is UnitCardData).Cast<UnitCardData>();
    public IEnumerable<ItemCardData> ItemCollection =>
        _collection.Where(c => c is ItemCardData).Cast<ItemCardData>();
}
```

---

```
public class Card
{
    protected readonly CardData data;

    protected Card (CardData data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public virtual void Use ();
}

public class UnitCard : Card
{
    public UnitCard (EnemyCardData data) : base(data)
    {
    }

    public UnitCardData UnitData => data as UnitCardData;

    public override void Use ()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

И какой нибудь генератор карт, который кастит типы данных и создает соответствующие карты

```
public static class CardDataExtension
{
    public static Card GetCard (this CardData data)
    {
        if (data is UnitCardData uData)
            return new UnitCard(uData);
        else if (data is ItemCardData iData)
            return new ItemCard(iData);
        else
            throw new Exception("unrecognized card data type");
    }
} 

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private CardsDataHolder _cards;

    public void DoSometing ()
    {
        var data = _cards.UnitCollection.First();
        UnitCard card = data.GetCard() as UnitCard;
    }
}
```